# Configuring ODBC to remote web server (QuickBooks Remote Connector)

Tags: networking, powerbi, odbc, quickbooks, windows-firewall

I have a local MAC machine that RDPs into a windows VM.  On that windows VM/desktop I have Power BI Desktop installed along with the Cdata PowerBI/Quickbooks ODBC driver (https://www.cdata.com/drivers/quickbooks/download/powerbi/).

On a separate server (which I can RDP into from the virtual machine) I have quickbooks desktop installed (https://www.acecloudhosting.com/) and in single-user mode (opened a company file w/ an admin user).  On that server I have also setup QuickBooks Remote Connector (http://remoteconnector.com/), which essentially is used to create an authenticated connection to QuickBooks.  This "remote connector" also acts as a lightweight web server that listens for incoming requests (such as a power bi direct query) and uses that to communicate with Quickbooks hosted on a separate server.

However, I keep getting an HTTP protocol error and not sure if it is because the ports are not setup properly or if something in my ODBC connection is incorrect.  It is very odd that I can RDP into the remote server from my VM, but when I try to ping the server my request time out despite allowing ICMP responses in the windows file sharing options so I find that odd.

I have worked on this for about 4 hours, but have run out of things to try.

http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RQB/odbc/pg_connectiono.htm

[image: bc]